# How to check duplicate in cross way?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
    Surnme|     forename|    work|  Creation date|  Active/inactive
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    satish| Amuluru     |   123 |   12/11/2016  |   D

   Amuluru| satish      |   123 |   16/11/2016  |   A

    satish| Amuluru     |  123  |  16/1/2016    |   D

    satish| Amuluru     |  123  |  16/1/2016    |   D

    mohamd| arashad     |   123 |               |   I
```

Here we want to compare 
here I have to find how many duplicate records are there and The crieteria for duplication is below.

1)cross checking means

(surname =forename or forename=surname) and work should same.

We update that Active/inactive column as "D" if that duplicate record does not contain latest creation date.
If that record contain latest creation date then update  Active/inactive column as "A".

2) Same matching.

(surname=surname or forename=forename) and work should same.

We update that Active/inactive column as "D" if that duplicate record does not contain latest creation date.
If that record contain latest creation date then update  Active/inactive column as "A".
And based on latest creation  date on duplicate record we have to update Active/inactive column as "A"
and which column don`t have duplicate record those will update  Active/inactive column as "I".
[image]
Here I am uploading image please prefer that one in this image i explain problem may be get clear idea.
Thanks .

Comment: It is not that hard. Hint: use `EXISTS(...)`

Comment: You could have the decency to provide table definition and Postgres version.

Comment: @ wildplasser, But using exists we can only do same matching ,what should I do for cross checking?

Comment: @ Erwin Brandstetter,  Postgres 9.6